# Can't pass serialized Json to Web API action

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-web-api2

> **NOTE** Please see the update at the bottom.

I'm picking up maintenance on an existing (working) application.

The application receives data into a class via a post to a Web API controller action.

However when I try to test this by posting it some data it just gives an empty object.

I assumed that my Json must be wrong so I tried sending the Json string as text and deserializing manually, and this works fine, returning the populated object I would expect to see.

I've searched online and seen various suggestions about adding attributes to the parameters but this doesn't do it for me.

The code looks pretty much as follows:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowBasicAuthentication]
    public async Task<MyResponse> ProcessData(
        [FromUri]string key, 
        [FromUri]string name, 
        [FromUri]string value1, 
        [FromBody] DataClass value // this is never populated
    )
    {
        // the following returns the data as expected
        var test = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<DataClass>(value1);
        ...
    }
```

The jQuery I'm using to test this is as follows:

```
$('#post').click(function () {

    var key = $('#key').val();

    var name = $('#name').val();

    var value1 = $('#value').text();
    var value = JSON.parse(value1);

    var url = '/api/ProcessData/?key=' + key
                  + '&name=' + name
                  + '&value1=' + value1

    /* with this post value appears in action as an instantiated but empty object */

    $.post(url, { value: value })
        .success(function (r) {
            ...
        })
        .fail(function (r) {
            ...
        })

    /* also tried the following, but value appears as null object

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: value,
        success: function (r) {
            alert(r);
        }
    });

    */

});
```

[EDIT]

Just to clarify, I added the value1 string parameter to test that the Json can be deserialized correctly, which it can, so the Json is ok and the class is ok.

**UPDATE**

This works when called from Postman so the error must be in the jQuery.
Can anyone show the correct way to do this?

Thanks

[/EDIT]

Comment: Could you show what `DataClass` looks like?

Comment: Does posting the json with postman work? I always use it to validate the api first, that way i know if its jquery bug or api!

Comment: Good idea I'll give Postman a go

Comment: What does this var value1 = $('#value').text(); contain? post a sample. You probably don't specify the json string correctly, does not match the DataClass definition.

Comment: have you tried "data: JSON.stringify(value)" ?

Comment: Also why you deserialize value1?  var test = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<DataClass>(value1); Your object must be in value parameter not value1.

Comment: @AndreiFilimon I just added value1 as a test to check the Json was being received correctly and can be deserialized correctly, which it can. Sorry I thought I explained that in the question.

Comment: `KISS` (keep it simple stupid) - bring it back to basics with as little moving parts as possible. Hard code your url as well the json you are sending in your $post call. Look in the browser's development console to see what is being sent, do a simple check for values on the server side. Once you get that to work extend it from there until you get to where you want to go. In short: **write the absolute minimum to get your test to work**. See also [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ChrisWatts It works fine when posted from Postman! I must be sending it wrong somehow from my jQuery.

Comment: The correct way of stringify the body object would be var data = JSON.parse({value: value1});

Comment: @MarcusH That causes an error - `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`

Comment: Ok, please update the question with DataClass.cs

Comment: @MarcusH _"The correct way of stringify the body object would be var data = JSON.parse({value: value1}); "_ . No. That would **un**-stringify it. And will fail because you passed it an object instead of a string. `JSON.stringify({value: value1});` will return `"{value: value1}"`. JSON.parse, passing in that string, would reverse the process.

Comment: @ADyson Afcourse, Didn't see that I typed parse. Meant stringify